# What is the equality of this integral which includes Dirac-Delta function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta, eigenfunctions

How to simplify the following 
$$\int_0^b\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i(x)Y_j(x)A(t)\delta(x-vt)dx=?$$
where 
$$ \{Y_i(x)\}_{i=1}^\infty=\Bigg\{\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{b}}\sin(c_ix)\Bigg\}_{i=1}^\infty$$
and
$c_i=i\pi/b.$

**The attemps:**
I know that

$\int_0^bY_i(x)Y_i(x)dx=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{b}}\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{b}}\int_0^b\sin(i\pi x/b)\sin(i\pi x/b)dx=\dfrac{2}{b}\dfrac{b}{2}=1$

if $0<vt<b$,

$\int_{0}^{b}A(t)\delta(x-vt)dx=A(vt)$

else it is zero.

But how can I use them in this question? Also, is there any possibility for getting rid of summations like $\sum_{i=1}^N$ bla bla...?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it $A(x)$ or $A(t)$ in the integrand? If $A(t)$, it just pulls out of the integral altogether.

Comment: it is $A(t)$. What is your solution? Could you explain some more?

Comment: Actually, $\displaystyle\int_0^b A(x) \, \delta(x-vt) \, dx=A(vt)$, if $0<vt<b$, whereas $\displaystyle\int_0^b A(t)\,\delta(x-vt)\,dx=A(t)$, if $0<vt<b$.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks. All right, how can we simplify this question?

Comment: Your $c_i$ information there allows us to perform the summation, which I've now included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac Delta function "picks out" the value of the integrand where the argument of the delta function is zero. So I would say that
\begin{align*}\int_0^b\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i(x)\,Y_j(x)\,A(t)\,\delta(x-vt)dx&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle A(t)\,Y_j(vt)\sum_{i=1}^N Y_i(vt), \quad &0<vt<b \\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle A(t)\,\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{b}}\sin(c_jvt)\sum_{i=1}^N \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{b}}\sin(c_ivt), \quad &0<vt<b \\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \dfrac{2A(t)}{b}\,\sin(c_jvt)\sum_{i=1}^N \sin(c_ivt), \quad &0<vt<b \\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \dfrac{2A(t)}{b}\,\sin\left(\frac{j\pi vt}{b}\right)\sum_{i=1}^N \sin\left(\frac{i\pi vt}{b}\right), \quad &0<vt<b \\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
&=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \dfrac{A(t)}{b}\,\sin\left(\frac{j\pi vt}{b}\right)\csc\left(\frac{\pi v t}{2b}\right)\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi v t}{2b}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{(1+2N)\pi v t}{2b}\right)\right], \quad &0<vt<b \\
0,\quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you. In this question,is there any possibility for getting rid of summations like $\sum_{i=1}^N$ bla bla.... ?

Comment: Only if you know the form of the $c_i$, and maybe not even then.

Comment: Dear Adrian, you are great:) thanks Could you explain some more how did you get rid of the sum?

Comment: @HD239: Thanks! You're very kind. That particular sum is a known trig identity. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities.

Comment: In the question, if it was $A_i(t)$ instead of $A(t)$, will the answer change or is it same? unfortunately, the question originally includes $A_i(t)$ not $A(t)$ . I recognized just now :( Sorry... many times..

Comment: That will change your answer drastically, because the $A_i(t)$ won't come out of the sum, and unless you have detailed information about $A_i(t)$, the sum will not just "go away".